# I build a News Website with Next.js Server Side rendering and the export const metadata = { title: "TEST" } is not taking action

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I have developed a News Website using Next.js with Server Side Rendering. In my pages, I'm utilizing export const metadata = { title: "TEST" } to set the page title, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I have checked my implementation, and the metadata object appears to be correctly structured. However, the page title remains unchanged.

Repository : https://github.com/BlendEmini/NewsBlog-ssr

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the metadata object is not affecting the page title as expected. If there's a better approach or if I'm missing something crucial in the Next.js setup for server-side rendering, please guide me in the right direction. Thank you for your assistance!

I've tried several methods to set the page title in my Next.js News Website. Initially, I used the  component, then attempted the older approach of defining metadata within the HTML, and finally, I adopted the recommended export const metadata method in each page file. Unfortunately, none of these methods have successfully changed the page title as expected. Despite meticulous checks, the title remains unaffected. I'm seeking guidance on potential issues or alternative approaches to ensure the correct display of page titles. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [`next-seo`](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo) which is best for this type of website, where you can configure the seo settings for each and every web page.

```
...
export default function Home({ blogs }) {
    return (
        <>
        <NextSeo
          title="News Website"
          description="News Website - description"
        />
            <div className="">
                <Navbar />
                ...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/BlendEmini/NewsBlog-ssr?view=editor)

[implementation reference](https://github.com/shivammodiin/nextvita/blob/main/pages/index.js)

Comment: Can i use NextSeo for dynamic routing based on id , with title,description and image (i need it for facebook ) ? Thanks btw for help :)

Comment: @BlendEmini Yes you can, get the static data from next.js SSR, then set the values on next seo meta tags!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using `pages` router instead of `app` router. Hence, you can use `<Head>` tag from `next/head`.

E.g.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
 
function Page() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Head>
        <title>title goes here</title>
      </Head>
    </section>
  )
}
 
export default Page;
```

For you reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head

Answer (score 0):

Its Exports a metadata object containing the title property, which represents the title of your webpage. *You can include other metadata properties as needed*

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Your Page Title",
  // Other metadata properties
};
```

Correctly import the metadata object and ensure it's structured with a title property in your metadata file. Use it to dynamically set the page title with the Head component from Next.js. Simply replace '../path/to/your/metadata/file' with the actual file path.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { metadata } from '../path/to/your/metadata/file';
export default function YourPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        {/* Other metadata tags */}
      </Head>
      {/* Your page content */}
    </>
  );
}
```